# Strategy for deleting a node in a graph represented by an adjacency list without hurting indexing

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-list

I have some trouble understanding adjacency lists and would like to hear your opinion or even better advice. :-)

**tl;dr**: Removing a node from an adjacency list breaks "indices". Is this avoidable, if yes, how?

**the long part**: In graph theory we learn that adjacency lists are (under certain conditions) an efficient way of storing directed graphs. Let's look at an example of a graph written in adjacency list notation.

```
0 -> 1, 2, 5
1 -> 2, 3
2 -> 1
3 -> 4
4 -> 5
```

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume we don't have additional properties (potential, cost,...) on the edges or nodes. To implement this we would trouble some array or list-kind-of-type in the programming language of our choice. I chose python for my demonstration.

```
adjacencies = [[1,2,5],[2,3],[1],[4],[5]]
```

This is a list of size 5. Each index in the list maps to an index in the adjacency notation.

```
adjacencies = [[1,2,5],[2,3],[1],[4],[5]]
#              <--0--> <-1-> <2> <3> <4>
# The angle brackets indicate which position maps to which node.
```

If we want to access all outgoing edges for node 1, we simply can do this via `adjacencies[1]` in concstant time.

Let's say I would like to remove a node, e.g. 2.

```
adjacencies = [[1,5],[3],[4],[5]] # Node 2 was removed from the adjacency list
#              <-0-> <1> <3> <4>
```

Naturally we lose the incoming edges (0,2), (1,2) and we lose the outgoing edge (2,1), too.

**Here is what troubles me.** Node 3 is now at position 2 which means acessing it via `adjacencies[3]` is wrong! Do I have to iterate the `adjacencies` list each time I want to access a node or do I misunderstand something which should be obvious? ( I implemented an adjacency list based graph structure in Java and I was tempted to chose a `Map<Integer,List<Edge>>` kind of  structure but I would like to understand how one could preserve the index consistency while doing this with plain arrays...)

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: An "index" or "position" of a node has nothing to do with the graph itself. It only has to do with how you have chosen to store the graph. The number you have on each node is just a label, which could be anything.

Comment: @bengoesboom: So the indices 0 to 5 are simply labels and have nothing to do with the positions they are written to? This means finding a node always cost me O(n), where n is the number of nodes in the graph, since I have to iterate over the array to find node with the correct "label", right?

Comment: Whether or not the numbers 0 to 5 mean something about position of storage is dependent on your implementation. "Adjacency list" is a conceptual way of storing a graph, not an implementation. If you implement an adjacency list with arrays, and use your labels as indices for your arrays, you run into this issue of it becoming difficult to remove elements, as well as forcing your node labels into being specific numbers.

Comment: @bengoesboom, it appears I truly confused the concept with an implementation suggestion. Thanks for the clarification. If you care to make your answer a comment, I will gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An "index" or "position" of a node has nothing to do with the graph itself. It only has to do with how you have chosen to store the graph. The number you have on each node is just a label, which could be anything.

Whether or not the numbers 0 to 5 mean something about position of storage is dependent on your implementation. "Adjacency list" is a conceptual way of storing a graph, not an implementation.
If you implement an adjacency list with arrays, and use your labels as indices for your arrays, you run into this issue of it becoming difficult to remove elements, as well as forcing your node labels into being specific numbers.